# How can i know when to use -webkit-, -moz, -ms-, -o-, etc?

Tags: css

How can i know when to use the prefix `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-ms-`, `-o-` in css properties? I see a lot of "inconsistency" in some attributes, in some properties the programmer only puts `-moz-`, in the other he puts the all 4. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: It's probably better to just use a post-processor (i.e. [PostCSS](http://postcss.org/)) to automatically add these types of things.

Comment: [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/) will let you know what browser versions support the property and if you need to use the vendor prefixes.

Comment: I agree, but i need understand first the rule, don't you agree? I must understand the concept before use something that helps me do the job.

Comment: The concept is that as browsers transition to a more standardized approach, some of them implement new features based on their interpretation of definitions in the W3C. As such, they first implement a prefixed version of the property and wait for it to become normalized amongst other browsers before enabling the non-prefixed version. Thus, some browser versions may require the prefix in order to get the desired result. Managing prefixes (and format variants) is a pain, so post/pre processors do the work for you. As for why some prefixes and not others, that is a question for the original dev.

Comment: A good example to illustrate @Martin's point: [Google's article about position: sticky](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit), which lists all 4 prefixes for position: sticky. Spoiler: -moz-sticky, -ms-sticky and -o-sticky have never been used by any browser in the last 4 and a half years since that article. Moz implements position: sticky *unprefixed*. Chrome [*dropped* it two years after that article](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=177128), but has since reinstated it, also unprefixed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To know what prefixes to use is based on what browsers **you** want to support. A good place to find out what browser versions require a prefix is [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com).

The variation is due to what browsers other developers have decided to support. If you see more prefixes then the developers (site owner) of the site have decided on a higher/deeper level of support for older browsers. Fewer prefixes will support fewer browsers. As to why? There could be a lot of reasons some are target audience and feature requirements (Web APIs).

You can go the manual route but a lot of developers will use tools like [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) or a CSS preprocessor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). These tools give you different ways of defining what prefixes to use.

With something like *AutoPrefixer* there's an option to list what browsers you want to support and it figures out what prefixes etc. are required to support those browsers based on the non-prefixed version.

With a CSS preprocessor like *SASS* or *LESS* you can create a *mixin* (basically a function) that will add the prefixes you've defined.

Answer (score 9):

I apply a simple rule of thumb: *never put a vendor prefix* (let user update their browser instead, and avoid non-official/non-yet-finalized CSS rules).

See http://shouldiprefix.com/ if you still want to know which prefixes are "required" (or "worth worrying about").

Last, CSS preprocessors can handle these, but it's often a useless pain to add to your development and release stack (except if you're using other stuff that vendor prefixes, or if you have to deal with old browsers like in companies intranets).

Answer (score 5):

awesome question.

A lot of Programmers use [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/) to determine if a particular CSS property is supported in all of the browsers they would like to support. If it's not fully-supported in all of the browsers they wish to support, the programmer should use the vendor prefix (i.e. -webkit-).

**Example Scenario**

Say the programmer wanted to use the Transform property ([CanIUse#Transform](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform)). See how Android Browser 4.4 & 4.4.4 have yellow warnings in the top right? Hover over them and notice it says 'Supported with -webkit'? This is exactly. when you would add the -webkit- vendor prefix.

I disagree that you have to add them all (although, it really doesn't hurt anything). If you just do a bit of research before you use newer CSS properties, you will have cleaner CSS/SASS/LESS/etc while supporting all of the browser your heart desires. :P

I do think there are awesome tools out there to do this automatically. Xenos mentioned a few.

Best of luck in your CSS endeavors.

Answer (score 5):

These different properties are termed as "vendor prefixes":
`-moz-` = used for Mozilla Firefox
`-ms-` = used for Microsoft Internet Explorer
`-o-` = used for Opera
`-webkit-` = used for Google Chrome and Apple Safari browsers.

It's always a good approach to use all the vendor prefixes for the css you're applying, in order to address to the browser compatibility of the webpage you're developing.

However, css preprocessors like LESS can handle this thing, if you happen to use them. I personally use LESS to handle all this vendor prefixing stuff and it's really simple. If I weren't using preprocessors, I would still have considered writing vendor prefix css along with the default property name.

It's always a good thing to keep addressing about the compatibility issues well in advance than to run into some and fixing them later.

Try using vendor prefixer tools like:
https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix

Answer (score 0):

If you want ensure that will work on each browser you need add all of them, some websites dont support old browsers so there is no need to care about browsers which you decide to not support :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found, if you are using Visual studio code go to extension and search for `css-auto-prefix`